# How to add row to table dynamically on button click with Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on Angular2 project and want to want to add rows to table dynamically, when a button is clicked. I know that `*ngFor` can be used to add rows dynamically, but I am interested if it is possible to use `*ngFor` only if button is clicked.

Comment: Yes. You can use `*ngIf` and set a boolean value. When you click the button set boolean value to true else false.

Comment: @randomSoul thank you, can you tell me how to add rows to table dynaimcally on each click, for example on first click add 10 rows, on second click add 10 more rows below the rows which I added on the first click and e.t.c

Comment: - Click on what? You mean `button`? You can get the last `id` and on every click send request to backend to get the next 10 records after the last object id and concatenate this array with the *ngFor variable. You need to apply check on limit of records at the backend.

Answer (score 1):

usually you use *ngFor to iterate over an array (generally of objects). So if your array is called "data" yo can have some like

```
<table *ngIf="data.length">  <!--Don't show nothing if no data-->
<tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let item of data">
   <td>{{item.firstName}}</td>
   <td>{{item.lastName}}</td>
   <td>{{item.age}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Where you has a variable data like

```
data:any[]=[] //don't forget initialize!
```

A button can execute some like

```
onClick()
{
   this.data.push({firstName:"firstName",lastName:"Last Name",age:18})
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A quick sample:

```
  <button (onClick)="sth=!sth">click</button>
       <div *ngIf="sth">
        <div *ngFor="...">
         ...
        </div>
       </div>
```